# Aura error: Assertion Failed $S.getCallback() callback must be a valid function

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have the following functions in the aura helper js file:

```js
getSearchTimeframePicklistValues: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getSearchTimeframePicklistValues");
    action.setCallback( this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var results = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.searchTimeframes", results.framesList);
            component.set("v.defaultTimeframeId", results.defaultId);
            component.find("searchTimeframePicklist").set("v.value", results.defaultId);
            component.set("v.selectedSearchTimeFrame", results.defaultId);
            window.setTimeout(
                $A.getCallback(this.setStartEndDates(component, event, helper))); 
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

setStartEndDates: function(component, event, helper) {
    var searchTimeframes = component.get("v.searchTimeframes");
    var selectedTimeFrame = component.get("v.selectedSearchTimeframe");
    var startingNumberOfDays, endingNumberOfDays;
    for (var i=0; i < searchTimeframes.length; i++) {
        if(selectedTimeFrame == searchTimeframes[i].Id) {
            startingNumberOfDays = searchTimeframes[i].Start__c;
            endingNumberOfDays = searchTimeframes[i].End__c;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(startingNumberOfDays == undefined && endingNumberOfDays == undefined)  {
        component.set("v.startDate", "");
        component.set("v.endDate", ""); 
    }
    else {
        component.set("v.startDate", helper.buildFormattedDate(startingNumberOfDays));
        component.set("v.endDate", helper.buildFormattedDate(endingNumberOfDays)); 
    }   
},
```

The `getSearchTimeframePicklistValues` function is called in the `doInit` function when the component initializes. I'm getting the following error:

> AuraError: Assertion Failed!: $A.getCallback(): 'callback' must be a valid Function : false`

Is the syntax wrong? Although I'm getting the error, if I close the error the UI displays the results correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getCallback()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_jsapi_dollarA_getCallback.htm) specifically calls this out:

> Don't use $A.getCallback() if your code is executed as part of the
> framework's call stack. For example, your code is handling an event or
> **in the callback for an Apex controller action**.

If you want to call the helper function after the apex controller runs, simply call it within the `setCallback` you've defined for it.

```javascript
getSearchTimeframePicklistValues: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getSearchTimeframePicklistValues");
    action.setCallback( this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var results = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.searchTimeframes", results.framesList);
            component.set("v.defaultTimeframeId", results.defaultId);
            component.find("searchTimeframePicklist").set("v.value", results.defaultId);
            component.set("v.selectedSearchTimeFrame", results.defaultId);
            <!-- call helper method after apex method runs successfully --> 
            this.setStartEndDates(component, event, helper); 
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```